# GPS integration to ROS via Arduino

Tags: navigation, arduino, gps, rosserial-arduino

Please I have some problems with this.

I am a beginner.

I want to send GPS data from a GPS connected via arduino to ROS.

My code arduino is as below:

```
/*
  Code to connect GPS to ROS via Arduino.
*/

// Include libraries
#include <ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/NavSatFix.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/TwistStamped.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/TimeReference.h>
#include <Adafruit_GPS.h>

// Define hardware serial port
//#define GPSSerial Serial1

Adafruit_GPS GPS(&Serial1);

ros::NodeHandle nh;

sensor_msgs::NavSatFix fix_msg;
geometry_msgs::TwistStamped vel_msg;
sensor_msgs::TimeReference time_ref_msg;

ros::Publisher fix_publisher("fix", &fix_msg);
ros::Publisher vel_publisher("vel", &vel_msg);
ros::Publisher time_ref_publisher("time_reference", &time_ref_msg);

char c;

void setup() {
  // Serial.begin(57600);
  nh.initNode();
  nh.advertise(fix_publisher);
  nh.advertise(vel_publisher);
  nh.advertise(time_ref_publisher);

  // Initialize the Adafruit GPS module with the correct baud rate for your GPS module.
  GPS.begin(9600); // Replace with your GPS module's baud rate
  GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_OUTPUT_RMCGGA);
  GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_UPDATE_1HZ);
  delay(1000); // Allow time for GPS module to initialize
}

void loop() {
  while (GPS.available()) {
    c = GPS.read();
    Serial.write(c);
  }

  if (c == '\n') {
    if (GPS.parse(GPS.lastNMEA())) {
      // Get the GPS data and extract relevant information
      float latitude = GPS.latitude;
      float longitude = GPS.longitude;
      float altitude = GPS.altitude;
      bool fix = GPS.fix;

      // Publish NavSatFix message
      fix_msg.header.stamp = nh.now();
      fix_msg.header.frame_id = "gps_link"; // Set the frame_id
      fix_msg.status.status = fix;
      fix_msg.latitude = latitude;
      fix_msg.longitude = longitude;
      fix_msg.altitude = altitude;

      // Set position covariance data
      fix_msg.position_covariance_type = 1;
      fix_msg.position_covariance[0] = 446.0544;
      fix_msg.position_covariance[1] = 0.0;
      fix_msg.position_covariance[2] = 0.0;
      fix_msg.position_covariance[3] = 0.0;
      fix_msg.position_covariance[4] = 446.0544;
      fix_msg.position_covariance[5] = 0.0;
      fix_msg.position_covariance[6] = 0.0;
      fix_msg.position_covariance[7] = 0.0;
      fix_msg.position_covariance[8] = 446.0544;

      // Publish GPS fix data
      fix_publisher.publish(&fix_msg);

      // Extract velocity information from GPS
      float velocity_knots = GPS.speed; // Knots
      float velocity_mps = velocity_knots * 0.514444; // Convert to m/s

      // Populate the TwistStamped message for velocity
      vel_msg.header.stamp = nh.now();
      vel_msg.header.frame_id = "gps"; // Set the frame_id
      vel_msg.twist.linear.x = velocity_mps;
      vel_publisher.publish(&vel_msg);

      // Populate the TimeReference message
      time_ref_msg.header.stamp = nh.now();
      time_ref_msg.header.frame_id = "gps"; // Set the frame_id
      time_ref_msg.time_ref = nh.now();
      time_ref_publisher.publish(&time_ref_msg);
    }
  }

  nh.spinOnce();
}
```

When I connect (rosrun rosserial_arduino serial_node.py _port:=/dev/ttyUSB1 _baud:=57600
) and run rostopic list, I can see the topics but when I run echo I don't get any response and it freezes.

When I check the serial terminal on arduino, I get to see the NMEA messages coming.

Please what can be problem?